# Paths in $\mathbb{R}$ are homotopic.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f$ and $g$ be paths in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is homotopic to $g$.

My attempt: To show that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are homotopic we must produce a continuous map $F:[0,1]\times [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x,0)=f(x)$ and $F(x,1)=g(x)$. Because $f$ and $g$ are paths, they are continuous so we can take $F$ to be $F(x,t)=(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)$. Is this a correct justification?

Comment: Yes, this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Yes, your approach works. You can easily verify that the same construction works for any two maps $f, g: X \to C$ where $X$ is an arbitrary topological space and $C$ is a convex subset of an arbitrary topological vector space $E$.